# Get Id of DataTables Dynamically

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to extract ID of table from datatables without specifying name of table in function.  For example : Instead of specifying **var tableName = $('#myTable').attr('name')** I want to pull table name without writing **#myTable**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      { extend : 'collection',
        text : '<i class="fa fa-bars">buttons</i>',
        buttons: [
          'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
          {
            text: 'Report Issue',
            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
              reportIssue(e, dt, node, config);
            }
          }
        ]
      }]
  } );

  // e - the button click event
  // dt - the datatable object
  // node - button node
  // config - the button's config (e.g. 'text')
  function reportIssue(e, dt, node, config) {    
    var tableName = $('#myTable').attr('name');
    alert( 'The "' + config.text + '" button was clicked\n' 
        + 'for the "' + tableName + '" table.' );
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables()

```js
$.fn.dataTable.tables().forEach(function(dt) {
  console.log( dt.id ) //in your case myTable
})
```

shorthand if you have only one table or know what to look for

```js
console.log( $.fn.dataTable.tables()[0].id ) //myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the datatable container using `dt.table().container()` and then find the table inside it:

```
function reportIssue(e, dt, node, config) {    
  var container = dt.table().container();
  var tableName = $(container).find("table").attr('name');
}
```